# Oracle 10g install on Windows 7 where to go the 10.2.0.5 Patch?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Hi i'm trying to get a couple of clients up and running, these are Windows 7 based machines 1 is 32bit the other 64. I have the install files for 10.2.0.3 and 10.2.0.4 for these environments but they require a patch file to update them to 10.2.0.5. This patch is only available to Support level Oracle logins, which I dont have, does anyone know where else I can get these patch files from?

files I curently have are
10203_vista_w2k8_x86_production_client.zip
10204_vista_w2k8_x64_production_client.zip
p8202632_10205_MSWIN-x86-64.zip

The last one is the Patch but only for 64 bit windows 7, I now require the 32bit version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a login to metalink, this suggests to me that perhaps you don't have an Oracle licence?

In which case wouldn't be entitled to software patches/updates.

Comment: thanks cowboy, but Oracle Licences are server based so for installing a client there shouldn't be any restriction. I dont know why Oracle hide the patch behind this requirement all of their client software is available using a normal logon.  the Patch is heavyWeight and I think it may contains DB stuff! So as far as I'm concerened my question still stands.

Comment: PurpleMonkey - Cagcowboy is correct.  The Oracle Support provides different options.  You can get access to support, patches and upgrades, etc based on the levels of support you "pay" for.  We are a development shop that supports both SQL and Oracle and we have to buy an oracle support so we can get these for testing.  I suggest you get with the DBA's managing the servers you are connecting the clients to to get the patches you require.

Comment: Thanks for the details, that makes sense in a way. Shame as I will have to wait for my DBA's to come though. cheers.